# click link selenium web driver works for ie not firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on. the code is simple:

```
//WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();  
//WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pa-u_14782488-bd']/a/span[2]")).click();
```

I use either ff or ie driver. but last 2 line of code is same. works for ie, but not ff. funny thing is i'm getting the xpath from ff firebug so xpath is correct for ff. ff version 7.0.1. Its just the Mail link on the left column of yahoos site. Why is this so hard?

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your issue, but the XPath expression `//*[@id='pa-u_14782488-bd']/a/span[2]` returns no elements. That's the problem with dynamic IDs. They don't last forever. Also, you're obviously clicking a link. Then try to click the link and not some of its inner `<span>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

As *Slanec* mentioned these kind of sites use dynamic id's,so a better option in the above specified case would be to use "title" attribute,which has lesser probability of changing..
if you want to go with xpath,this will work,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Mail']")).click();
```

Even better option will be to use **link text**,because it works the same way as the user manually would click...

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("MAIL")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has a hard time sometimes with elements embedded within link (`<a>`) elements. Try your code without the last part of the XPath. So:

```
//*[@id='pa-u_14782488-bd']/a
```

Make sure you also post what version of Selenium you are using so others can give you more detailed help.

Comment: thank you. i tried that but to no avail. still does not work for ff. i'm using selenium 2.11.0

Comment: I think it has to do with yahoo moving the web page down when their home page is loaded by ff. I notice that ie doesn't move the page dow. that may be throwing off the driver or something. any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that when selenium launches firefox ff it moves the web page down so that the element that i'm clicking on is at the very top of page. I tried different elements and it did the same thing. The problem with moving the page down on yahoo, it causes a message bar to appear on top of page which will cover the element. Wonder if that is causing the problem. I REALLY THINK THAT IS THE PROBLEM.

Comment: @emacs: Yes, that's probably the problem.  WebDriver won't click on an element that isn't visible to click on.

Comment: I tried this too, used different techniques like css selector etc but it did not work for me on firefox either. This is definitely a bug and you might want to consider opening one. Since this is easily reproducible, hopefully developers would be able to provide fix quickly - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list

Comment: @emacs If this actually is the problem, you can click the element via JS as a workaround: `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", foundElement);`

Answer (score 0):

dont use xpath search.. its highly unstable and doesnt help your case at all. Also your selenium code is now tightly coupled with the markup and any changes to the markup like introduction of a container (i.e div) will fail the test.

you could use scoping to achieve something similar. example:

```
var container=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pa-u_14782488-bd']"));

var spans=container.findElements(By.tagName("span"));

spans[1].Click();
```

Also I dont understand how this works though, cos you have a link and for I am guessing for styling purposes you have two spans within it but clicking on either of them should still trigger the same action as clicking on the click correcT?or am I missing something??

It might just be the case that firefox is handing your events in an incorrect way.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the outcome of the xpath stability research. Surely xpath, css or however you find the element will return the same IWebElement the Click() is run on or am I missing something?